# Incorrectly formated date shows up out of nowhere in DB via DBDataAdapter.Update - where does it get the format?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've been trying to figure this one with my colleagues for a while without success.

We have a .NET application that imports data into a database, including a date/datetime saved into a varchar column. On one system, the date seems randomly in a different format than expected, which is causing issues down the line.

Instead of expected YYYY-mm-dd we are getting MMM dd YYYY i.e. 2021-02-10 shows up as Feb 02 2021.
We can't find where it comes from. The user running the application has culture en_US. No date formats have been changed. Everything we can see in SQL server and in Windows is set to English (United States), Get-Culture applet returns the same values. dbcc useroptions show us_english as language and dateformat as mdy on both good and bad servers.

Where else could the SQL adapter code be looking for a culture/locale/date format (at some point in adapter.Update there must be an implicit conversion as the update command comes through as text (and is a simple `set {0} = @{0}` construct)?

I understand that this is not a good design and either a datetime column should be used or an explicit conversion before storing the date in the datatable, but this is not something I am able to change.

Comment: You should use a DATETIME column and not a VARCHAR column. How do you insert the data on the C# side?

Comment: `a date/datetime saved into a varchar column` (why?) - presumably whatever inserted it was responsible for the format.

Comment: *"including a date/datetime saved into a varchar column"* That there is your problem. There is only one fix, fix the design, make the data type a date and time data type, and ensure you parametrise your query's properly using `Parameters.Add`, not `set {0} = @{0}` (which is just disguised injection).

Comment: Yes, I understand this is not good design practice, but I am not able to change the application.

Comment: Then speak to whomever can, @Fabo.sk . It needs to be. End of story.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The entry is inserted/updated by System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable) method.
The underlying DataTable contains a datetime type column. 
At update time, it is being converted... inconsistently between machines.

Comment: @Larnu: Not an option. Yeah, I know, it should be. But I work with what I have. It works fine on 99% of machines, just this one is different, for some reason.

Comment: @Fabo.sk Are you using any typed dataset?

Comment: Try googling `dbdataadapter.update date format` - there were some hits that looked promising, I think.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida as far as I can tell the dataset is dynamically constructed based on input (both number of input columns and their type)

Comment: @Fabo.sk can you post the code where and how the data is updated in dataset?

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida basically this

`string typeName = col.DataType.UnderlyingSystemType.Name.ToLower(); 
switch ( typeName ) { 
case "datetime": 
// there are dates in _input_ that do not have month and day set 
 DateTime newDate; 
 newValue = newValue.Replace("/00", "/01");
 try {
  string[] a = newValue.Split('/');
  if ( a.Length == 3 ) { 
   newDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(a[0]), Convert.ToInt32(a[1]), Convert.ToInt32(a[2]));
  row[col] = newDate;
 }`

Comment: @Fabo.sk Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? The code contains a column `col` for which there are no details and there is a `newValue` which is not defined.

Comment: Urghh that is the horriblest date handling code I've seen outside of TheDailyWTF.com, `DateTime.Parse` and `ParseExact` are there for a reason, never mind you shouldn't store dates in varchar

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to provide whole reproducible example unfortunately.

row and col refer to datarow and datacolumn references, newValue is the new value supposed to be put in.
The application processes the input field by field, calling a method to store value in output datatable which checks what type the column is, sanitizes the input accordingly and saves it to the appropriate output datatable field.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm quite surprised it has worked for years as is, but... it did.